# Google Map road label/icon text illegible

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've customised a Google Map using SnazzyMaps. I used this theme as a base and then tweaked it to meet my needs: https://snazzymaps.com/style/8097/wy

One thing I noticed when I zoomed out the map was that the road signs were a grey block and you can't read the text. It's odd because if you zoom in they're fine. I guess they must be slightly different types of roads.

You can't see the issue on the default location (New York) but if you put "London" in the search box to change location, you'll see a lot of the road signs are blanked out - you may need to zoom out.

Here is my theme (json), it has the same issue and I can't rectify it:

```
[  
   {  
      "featureType":"all",
      "elementType":"geometry.fill",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "weight":"2.00"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"all",
      "elementType":"geometry.stroke",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "color":"#9c9c9c"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"all",
      "elementType":"labels.text",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "visibility":"on"
         },
         {  
            "color":"#404546"
         },
         {  
            "weight":".25"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"all",
      "elementType":"labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "color":"#ffffff"
         },
         {  
            "weight":"2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"landscape",
      "elementType":"all",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "color":"#f2f2f2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"landscape",
      "elementType":"geometry.fill",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "color":"#ffffff"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"landscape.man_made",
      "elementType":"geometry.fill",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "color":"#ffffff"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"poi",
      "elementType":"all",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "visibility":"off"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"road",
      "elementType":"all",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "saturation":-100
         },
         {  
            "lightness":45
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"road",
      "elementType":"geometry.fill",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "color":"#eeeeee"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"road",
      "elementType":"labels.text.fill",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "color":"#7b7b7b"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"road",
      "elementType":"labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "color":"#ffffff"
         },
         {  
            "weight":"3"
         },
         {  
            "visibility":"on"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"road.highway",
      "elementType":"all",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "visibility":"simplified"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"road.arterial",
      "elementType":"labels.icon",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "visibility":"off"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"transit",
      "elementType":"all",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "visibility":"off"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"transit.line",
      "elementType":"all",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "visibility":"on"
         },
         {  
            "weight":".75"
         },
         {  
            "color":"#b1b6b7"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"transit.station",
      "elementType":"labels.text",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "visibility":"simplified"
         },
         {  
            "color":"#404546"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"transit.station",
      "elementType":"labels.icon",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "visibility":"on"
         },
         {  
            "hue":"#b7ff00"
         },
         {  
            "gamma":"0.80"
         },
         {  
            "saturation":"-20"
         },
         {  
            "lightness":"0"
         },
         {  
            "weight":"1"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"water",
      "elementType":"all",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "color":"#46bcec"
         },
         {  
            "visibility":"on"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"water",
      "elementType":"geometry.fill",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "color":"#c8d7d4"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"water",
      "elementType":"labels.text.fill",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "color":"#070707"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "featureType":"water",
      "elementType":"labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers":[  
         {  
            "color":"#ffffff"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I thought it was something I'd done but it's in the base theme too. I found what I thought specified the road label styles and I was able to change the colour/hue of it but I couldn't fine a way to change the text. I even tried tweaking the Saturation/Lightness/Gamma to see if it was the contrast but no luck.

What am I missing? Hope someone can help with this but I guess it might be a bit of a niche problem.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've come across [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3591) in Google Maps that was logged around 5 years ago and hasn't been resolved yet.

Most road labels in Europe are styled fine but A Road labels are the exception. It's because the label is yellow text on a green background which really doesn't work with changing the saturation.

The best you can do is hide the labels completely (which isn't great) or put up with a bit of color and just tone down the labels a little.

In the style you gave, you can tweak the colors of these labels on `Roads > All > Color Options`. Or remove the styles from the parent and style the `Highway > Labels` directly. I've created an example style [here](https://snazzymaps.com/style/96363/wy-with-uk-a-road-labels).

In the end, these are all just workarounds for the above issue which probably won't be fixed any time soon. Hopefully that helps you out!

Comment: Thanks! It's a shame they haven't fixed this, 5 years! It's not ideal but for what I'm using it for I think I'll just disable Highway Roads and re-enable "Controlled Access" for now. That seems to do the trick. Thanks again!